# how to create one docker image for .Net Core2.2 and Angular7 apps?

Tags: angular, docker, asp.net-core

I have an angular7 app that is located in a folder named front alongside my .Net Core 2.2 folders like Controllers etc. how can I create one image for both my .Net Core and Angular apps? is it possible?
here is my dockerfile and my docker-compose file right now:
Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o out

# ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.0'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:latest
     command: --lower_case_table_names=1
     environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: test
       MYSQL_USER: test
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
     volumes:
       - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
       - _MySQL_Init_Script:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
     restart: always
   onlinesm.logs:
     image: test
     build: 
       context:  .
     ports:
       - "8080:80"
volumes:
  dbdata: {}
  _MySQL_Init_Script : {}
```

Comment: It's preferable to have them be separate containers anyways. The whole point of containerization is separate concerns, so you can individually spin up/down and scale up/down apps.If you did make them use the same container, then a change to your Angular app necessitates bringing down your ASP.NET Core app and vice versa, whereas in separate containers you can make changes individually. Additionally, you may want to scale to multiple instances of your ASP.NET Core app, but it's highly unlikely you'd ever need more than one instance of the Angular app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right your problem.

You need to copy Angular code into a container.

Your Dockerfile will be:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o out

# ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Development

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
#Copy static content
COPY front/ /app/front/
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "test.dll"]
```

Now you need configure your app to take frontend from /app/front directory.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("/app/front"),
        RequestPath = "/front"
    });
}
```

Sorry for my bad C#... [Here the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2)